# Application suspension for Spam and Placement in the Store

Tags: android, google-play, policy

Maybe this is not the right place to ask this but I do not know where to ask :(, from android support team nobody have answered to me.

If someone know the right place to ask this kind of question then please tall me where to ask.

I read from here

http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html

this is the sentence I do not get it "Developers also should not attempt to change the placement of any Product in the Store by rating an application multiple times, or by offering incentives to users to rate an application with higher or lower ratings."

Specifically this part ",or by offering incentives to users to rate an application with higher or lower ratings"

is this mean that if I offer button to rate my app then my app breaks the developer-content-policy ?

For example if I have something like this image is this means that my app breaks the android developer-content-policy ???

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can have a button to invite people to rate the app, but you cannot give any benefits to those persons, that's what the line in question says.

Comment: so you want to say that it is illegal if I pay money to the users if they rate my app ? ... If I get you right it is completely safe to have a button to offer people to rate you app ?

Comment: not only paying money, also offering any type of benefit: could be a pro version of the app or virtual money to spend in the app. At least that's what's written in english ;)